# Are old podcast episodes removed from the iTunes store?

Tags: itunes, podcasts

Today I realized I sort of abandoned podcasts a while ago, and I went to the iTunes store to look for good ones. Every podcast I looked at, though, only displayed some of the more recent episodes. I want to start at the beginning of these! [Here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/coding-101-mp3/id804926728?mt=2) [are](https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/the-moth-podcast/id275699983?mt=2) [just](https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/npr-programs-wait-wait.../id121493804?mt=2) [a](https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/the-stack-exchange-podcast/id279215411?mt=2) [few](https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/this-week-in-tech-video-hd/id478840375?mt=2) [examples](https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/they-might-be-giants-podcast/id105708952?mt=2).

Is iTunes deleting old episodes from their store? If so, is there any pattern to it? (WWDTM only has a few months of podcasts, while the Stack Exchange podcast has a few years' worth, yet both are missing the older episodes.)

Regardless of what's causing it, is there anywhere I can find the old episodes?

Answer (score 2):

If the podcast's feed has history archived in the [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/) (which many are), you can use [Backfeed](http://backfeed.strangecode.com/)<sup>1</sup> to generate a feed which includes all current and often<sup>2</sup>, all historical episodes.

---

<sub>1. disclaimer: I created Backfeed, since I was annoyed at the same problem.

2. limited by what is available in the wayback machine within a sane number of API requests.</sub>

Comment: Brilliant invention!

Answer (score 0):

I used to run a podcast long ago. My experience was, once I stopped updating, they began to be removed. I can't say with any certainty how much time has to pass. But I think Apple goes through and removes them. They're not hosted by Apple, at least they weren't then, so it's not a storage issue.

Comment: Nearly all of the podcasts I linked to are still updating, so that's definitely not the issue. However, I didn't know that podcast episodes aren't hosted on Apple's servers. Is that the case, or did I misunderstand? If so, it seems to me like that's the most likely explanation.

Comment: yeah that was at least the case when I was doing mine. I had to host them on my own. The way it worked was you would just provide Apple with an RSS feed of the episodes, formatted a special way. So iTunes was essentially a glorified link to the content elsewhere. I highly doubt they've changed the practice, as hosting so many podcasts wouldn't be very economical for them. So perhaps those episodes have simply been removed from the hosted servers... or their RSS feeds are messed up.